How do I create an event subscription that writes to a storage account queue in Azure?
I am getting a permissions error message when I try to create a new subscription for my event grid topic.  I'm trying to write to a storage account queue.  I have created a user assigned managed identity and assigned what I understood was needed but clearly I"m missing something.   Can you tell me which permissions I'm missing?
Here's the error:

Here's the roles assigned to the user assigned managed identity:

Here's the IAM section for the storage account:

And for the grid topic:

Additional Comments
This article basically describes the flow I want, but doesn't really address the RBAC side of things:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/custom-event-to-queue-storage#send-an-event-to-your-custom-topic

I found this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/custom-event-to-queue-storage#send-an-event-to-your-custom-topic
It has a destination and role chart.
to send to queues, I need to add Storage Queue Data Message Sender.
